# How to create a multiple dataframes from a file?

Tags: python, pandas, database, list, csv

I have multiple txt files which look like this:

```
[Level1]
Location = "London"
Type= "GTHY66"
Date = "16-11-2021"
Energy level = "Critical zero"
[Level2]
0.000   26.788
0.027   26.807
0.053   26.860
```

So from every file I read/process I want to create two data frames (Which eventually I will push to  a database).

**The dataframe in level1 needs to be `df_level1`:**

```
Location   Type      Date         Energy
London     GTHY66    16-11-2021   Critical zero
```

**The dataframe under level1 needs to be `df_level2`:**

```
Speed   Energylevel
0.000   26.788
0.027   26.807
0.053   26.860
```

This is what I tried, but I got stuck:

```
energy_root= r'c:\data\Desktop\Studio\Energyfiles'

#create list of file paths
def read_txt_file(path):
    list_file_path = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                file_name = os.path.basename(file)
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                list_file_path.append(file_path)
    
    return list_file_path     

def create_df():
    for file in read_txt_file(energy_root):
        file_name = os.path.basename(file)
        file_path = os.path.join(energy_root, file_name)
        datetime = re.findall(r'_(\d{8}_\d{6})\.', file_name)[0]

        with open(file_path, 'r+') as output:
            reader = output.readlines()
            for row in reader:
                d = row.split('=')
                if len(d) > 1:
                   df_level1 = pd.DataFrame([d[1]], columns=[d[0]])

                   print(df_level1 )
              "then create df_level2 ....."

create_df()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with the correct separators, but you have to do 2 things:

1. Before: Split the parts of the file for Level1 and Level2
2. After: Transpose and set the columns of Level1

Here's the code, straight inside your `with open [...]` line

```py
reader = output.read() # simply the entire file text, not split into lines
parts = reader.split('[Level2]\n')
lvl1_lines = parts[0].split('[Level1]\n')[1].replace('"','')
lvl2_lines = "Speed   Energylevel\n" + parts[1]

from io import StringIO # to read strings as files for read_csv
df_level1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(lvl1_lines), sep='\s*=\s*', engine='python').transpose().reset_index()
df_level1.columns = df_level1.iloc[0] # set the correct column names
df_level1 = df_level1[1:] # remove the column row
df_level2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(lvl2_lines), sep='\\s+')
```

Comment: Adam.Er8 Speed + EnergyLEvel gets shows as 1 column while they need to be seperate columns....

Comment: @Al-Andalus OK, I replaced the separator with `\\s+` (one or more spaces) instead of the tab I initially thought it was. works now?

Comment: By the way, I miss a column in my `df_level1`. When I do `print(df_level1.columns)` I get : `Index(['Type', 'Date ', 'Energy level '], dtype='object', name='Location ')`. The question is: Where is column Location, why is it not being seen as a column?

Comment: @Al-Andalus oops, I forgot to `reset_index` after the transpose, now it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def read_txt_file(path):
    n = 0
    pattern = re.compile(r'(.+)\s*=\s*\"(.+)\"')
    level1 = {}
    with open(path) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            line = line.strip()
            n += 1
            if line == '[Level2]':
                break
            
            m = pattern.match(line)
            if m is not None:
                key = m.group(1)
                value = m.group(2)
                level1[key] = value

    level1 = pd.DataFrame(level1, index=[0])
    level2 = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\s+', skiprows=n, header=None, names=['Speed', 'EnergyLevel'])
    return level1, level2
```

Usage:

```py
level1, level2 = read_txt_file('data.txt')
```

Comment: I tried yours out, but this seems only to work if a level1 only has 4 records and level2 3 records.  Some files have 20 records below level1 and 40 or 50 records below level2. How is that fixable?

Comment: It was written for arbitrary number of lines in both level 1 and 2. My tests work as expected. Can you post the troublesome file?

Comment: They are quiet big. How can I share them with you?

Comment: You can trim it down to just enough to demonstrate the problem and edit your question to include the file